# After creating a bootable pendrive the size of storage space reduced in Pendrive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, format

I had created my pendrive as bootable drive to install windows 7, After installing windows, i formatted my pen drive but it shows ******3.72 GB free of 3.77 GB******

While i was trying to repair the same with chkdsk command, i came across this data as in screenshot below [command : "chkdsk I:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPED.png)

Even after formatting this pendrive, the same output is available.

The result shows me there are few files that are occupying this space. Can anyone suggest, how is this possible?

------------------------Edited--------------------------------

Basically what are these files and can they be viewed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you consider any storage device, its capacity is measured in raw units. Formatting the storage device imposes a logical arrangement of that physical space. Since the logical arrangement depends on the particular operating system, the addressing of the logical space is always less than the physical one.

An analogy may clarify this: assume a terrain measuring 10 Km2 in which you have to build streets and sidewalks to access the lots where people can build their houses. It is clear that since streets and sidewalks occupy some space, the usable area to build things has to be less than 10 Km2.

To ease things up, storage devices always contain certain files which allows the operating system to understand how is organized the information within that drive.

Comment: I agree with the fact that you are explaining, say for example a 4GB pendrive has 3.77GB units of space available in total to store anything.
But here as you can see in the [image] [link],

The last 2 lines how that
Total allocation units on disk and allocation units available on disk are 989167 and 978115 respectively. 

Where in (989167*4096) / (1024*1024*1024) = 3.77GB for this 4GB pendrive

This does not explain the reason for 21568KB occupied by 5 files.

[link]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPED.png